# Уведомления с сайта в WhatsApp

Tags: php

Возможно ли сделать на сайте уведомления по WhatsApp? То есть, к примеру, на сайте зарегистрировался новый пользователь и мне в WhatsApp с сайта приходит уведомление. Как подобное можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для отправки WhatsApp сообщений с сайта можно использовать [Chat-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API).

Пример кода:

```php
$username = "79876543210"; // номер
$nickname = "MySite"; // ник
$password = "***"; // пароль

$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname);
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);

$target = '79870123456'; // получатель
$message = 'Сообщение';

$w->sendMessage($target , $message);
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет раскурю сейчас, жаль все на инглише только\ возможно это то что мне нужно